# Writing a function that determines if both integers a user enters are odd numbers

Tags: javascript, function, integer

How would you write a function that determines if the two numbers a user enters is both odd and returns a boolean value that is true if both numbers are odd? I already know how to write a function that determines if the two numbers a user enters is even or not.

Comment: In what sense is your second sentence not a statement to the effect that you know the answer to the question in your first sentence?

Answer (score 1):

That pretty easy and simple

```
numbersOdd(1,2); // return false
numbersOdd(14, 222); // return true;

function numbersOdd(n1, n2) {
  return n1%2 === 1 && n2%2 === 1;
}
```

Comment: A) Those should both return true; B) Your function checks if they are both even, not both odd.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
    function bothOdd(num1, num2) {
        if (num1 % 2 == 1 && num2 % 2 == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    window.alert(bothOdd(1, 2));
    window.alert(bothOdd(1, 1));
```